# Azure data factory V2 copy data issue - error code: 2200 An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from a csv file into the Azure sql but I am getting an unique error only during the deployment of pipeline. I am using a normal copy data

> {
> "errorCode": "2200",
> "message": "ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
> value of the property '' is invalid: 'An item with the same key has
> already been
> added.'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=An item with
> the same key has already been added.,Source=mscorlib,'",
> "failureType": "UserError",
> "target": "Copy data1",
> "details": [] }

Kindly help to solve

Comment: Can you show us your structure of table in your sql server and a sample csv file like yours?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, while copying a csv file to parquet using a copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

The above error is due to a duplicate column/header in the csv file. The exception message states *An item with the same key has already been added* that is the duplicate column might be getting added to a dictionary and the exception has been thrown.